# Capture events in cloudwatch with target sns

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

How to create sns target mesage attributes from the cloud watch event rules.

I have created a event rule which listen to job status with target as SNS.
And i do a fan out to SQS and have a filter based on states.
So how to pass message attributes to sns through cloud watch event?

I want to pass the event state as sns mesaage attribute so that i can filter on state attribute